# Rustlang sending generic data with channel? Which traits/ markers have to be implemented to do that?

Tags: generics, rust

Which traits and markers have to be implemented on a generic type T so that it could be send over channels? The Type T shall not contain any references and own all its contents its 'pure' from any reference (so it is guaranteed to be owned by its scope only). The same is true for all of T's nested fields. So that no lifetime specifier would be required, to transfer ownership. Which traits does i32 implement, that my genric type T does not implement to prevent the error fn from compiling?

```rust
fn error<T: Send+Sized>(mut data: Vec<T>)->Receiver<T>{
    let (s, r) = channel();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        while let Some(nextthing) = data.pop(){
            s.send(nextthing);
        }
    });
    r
}
```

as opposed to

```rust
fn thisworks(mut data: Vec<i32>)->Receiver<i32>{
    let (s, r) = channel();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        while let Some(nextthing) = data.pop(){
            s.send(nextthing);
        }
    });
    r    
}
```

Error: i just want it to  work like for i32: The ownership is just cleanly transferred without questions for lifetimes (maybe has something to do with the Primitive type and i32's copy trait?)

```
rror[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
5 | fn error<T: Send+Sized>(mut data: Vec<T>)->Receiver<T>{
  |          -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
6 |     let (s, r) = channel();
7 |     std::thread::spawn(move ||{
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:7:24: 11:6 data:std::vec::Vec<T>, s:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     std::thread::spawn(move ||{
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
error: Could not compile `playground`.
```

The playground link is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=117113384490f15bb33ff8f749661769

Comment: `Sized` is a default bound for generics; you don't need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about the type, it's about the lifetime of the type.

The compiler error was spot-on. The only change you require is this line:

```
fn error<T: Send+Sized+'static>(mut data: Vec<T>)->Receiver<T>{
```

This addition of `'static` is an additional requirement that the type must not be ephemeral; i.e. it must be defined for the lifetime of the program. This does not mean that the object **itself** must have a `'static` lifetime, just the type.

Comment: Is there more info available on what it means for a type to have a lifetime? Or what it means for a type to be ephemeral? I assumed `+'static` meant that any references that an instance of `T` might contain have to be valid for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: I can certainly find you a ton of [issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md) where this caused problems. Let's see if I can find you the doc for where it is actually fully described.

Comment: [Found it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_bounds.html). The exact condition imposed by `'static` in this case is that all references inside type T must outlive `'static` (which makes sense, as it'll cross thread boundaries)

Comment: so does a i32 have a 'static lifetime to?

Comment: An `i32` contains no reference.

Comment: That's the important thing, the `'static` lifetime on a trait means that everything in the trait **needs to live as long as that**.

Comment: so does a i32 type has the 'static lifetime to? I mean the i32 that is stored inside thisworks fn. Thank you for the clarification **"This does not mean that the object itself must have a 'static lifetime, just the type."** ... which implies, that Types can be created at runtime (there are types, which have not a 'static lifetime, e.g. closures)?

Comment: you said **An i32 contains no reference**. can i define a genric type T that has the same trait as i32 in this case and is guaranteed to contain no reference by trait bounds?

Comment: I knew I was going to get in trouble for mentioning this one day ;-) the short answer is I don't think you can. I certainly don't think I've ever felt the need to.

Comment: Regarding the *no inner reference lasting less than* rule, all primitive types are `'static`. All fully-owned types are `'static`. Anything with a reference in it can be `'static` if the reference is also `'static` (which practically never happens). It's the same rules as lifetimes, just applied generally to anything in the trait.

Comment: If I can only send data with the type T: Send+'static over channels, why isn't any type that implements Send automatically 'static too?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html ... only because unsafe impl of Send is possible too, right?

Comment: The requirement for `'static` in your case isn't due to `Send`, it is due to `thread::spawn`. If you had used, say, [`thread::scoped`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/std/thread/fn.scoped.html) the lifetime requirement would've different.